# Checking a property being passed on Expect.Call in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to test a method that does an update in `Rhino Mocks`. The class being passed to the update is quite rich, so I just want to check one property of it (the status).

Is there a simple way to do this with `Expect.Call()`?

Comment: What you mean by update? Give some code samples

Comment: I mean that it's calling a method and I want to be able to inspect the arguments being passed in

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you have instance of some class which is passed in 
`Update()` method and you want to ensure that `Update()` method set a `Status` property of the passed in object to some expected value.

So let's imagine some virtue classes since you've not provided any code:

```
IInstance mockedInstance = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IInstance>();
mockedInstance.Expect(m => m.Status).PropertyBehaviour().Repeat.Any();
mockedInstance.Status = "Some initial status value";

someService.Update(mockedInstance);
Assert.AreEqual("Post Update status value", mockedInstance.Status);
```